# When does chain termination occur exactly?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In the reaction of substitution of alkane. There are chain initiation, chain propagation and chain termination. However, when does the chain termination reaction occur? Does it occur simultaneously with the chain propagation reaction and once all the radicals run out, the reaction stop? Or it will occur after the chain propagation reaction finishes?

Comment: This is chemistry. If a reaction can occur, it will occur. Really, imagine two radicals which are about to terminate each other. Do you think they will stop at the mere _thought_ that there might be some unreacted starting compounds at the far corner of the vessel?

Comment: Reminds me of an answer I wrote a while ago about combustion, which is (for a large part) also a radical reaction. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/101967/17952