# What is Brown's Gas

Tags: thermodynamics

I've recently heard references to something called "Brown's Gas" which can be used to cut/weld metal but is regarded as 'a cold flame'. Does it actually exist and if so, why is it not widely used?

Comment: Might get some traction on Skeptics.SE on this one.

Comment: I guess you could consider the flame "cold", but only relative to things like acetylene or dicyanoacetylene.  The [adiabatic flame temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_flame_temperature) is 3200 $\unicode{x2103}$.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4018/differences-between-h-h-o-and-h-o-h

Answer (score 2):

Brown's gas is actually hydrogen-knallgas, a 2:1 mixture of hydrogen and oxygen.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyhydrogen.